# isGooglePlayServicesAvailable causes TransactionTooLargeException in Android 5

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have a crash reported by Fabric that during the check for the availability of Google Play Services that on Android 5 devices a crash can occur, particularly in OnePlus, Sony and Zuk devices.

I do not explicitly call this code directly and seems to be invoked by Google's own code.

According to other posts the exeption is thrown when the Parcel is too large, however since I do not control the process, my own code is not responsible for creating the Parcel.

I have checked the release notes for Google Play Services and other posts for no avail. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:112)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.zzo.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.zze.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbr.connect(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbp.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbp.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
Caused by android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Binder.java)
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
       at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getPackageInfo(IPackageManager.java:1876)
       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:107)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.zzo.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.zze.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbr.connect(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbp.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbp.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to official Android documentation, the key to [avoiding TransactionTooLargeException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html) is to

> keep all transactions relatively small. Try to minimize the amount of
>   memory needed to create a Parcel for the arguments and the return
>   value of the remote procedure call. Avoid transferring huge arrays of
>   strings or large bitmaps. If possible, try to break up big requests
>   into smaller pieces.

Comment: It totally agree, however this is not code I control as it is invoked by Google Play Services, therefore I cannot fix this by following the guide you outlined.